# How do I integrate a function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, and find no answer to the following:

I have a formula that calculates a result of two numbers from user input​​.

- How should the header file (".h") look, which contains this formula?
- How do I get the formula from the source code (".cpp")?
- How do I pass the result to the source code (".cpp")?

For you old-timers this is not a topic. Where can I find a good tutorial on C + +?

Greetings, Dino

Comment: What is "a result of two values"? Like the result of 3 and 5?

Comment: Is your "formula" a fixed part of your program, or is it some user input?

Comment: You should start with a C++ tutorial and come back later in a week or so. Use Google to find one.

Comment: Here is where you can find a tutorial : https://www.google.com/search?q=a+good+tutorial+on+C%2B%2B

Comment: I formulated the question again, and I hope it is now clearer. Unfortunately. English is not my native language :-(

Comment: Thanks hamon and Luchian for your helpful reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tutorials can be found in books. There's numerous topics on SO with good books recommendations.

In C++, free-standing functions should be either grouped in namespaces or as `static` class members (but only if they are logically connected to a class).

For your case, I'd go with the `namespace`. Even so, there 3 possibilities, out of which 2 are prefferable:

1) *declare* the function in a header and *define* it in a source file:

```
//formulas.h
#ifndef FORMULAS_H
#define FORMULAS_H
namespace Formulas
{
   int myFormula(int,int);
};
#endif
```

The preprocessor directives are include guards (you can google that). After this, you define it in a source file:

```
//formulas.cpp

#include "formulas.h"
namespace Formulas
{
    int myFormula(int, int)
    {
       //....
       return 42;
    }
}
```

2) Both declare and define the function in the header as `inline` (this will prevent multiple definitions of the functions). Usually done with relatively small functions that are called frequently, to prevent the call overhead and allow better optmizations:

```
//formulas.h
#ifndef FORMULAS_H
#define FORMULAS_H
namespace Formulas
{
   inline int myFormula(int,int)
   {
       //...
       return 42;
   }
};
#endif
```

3) Declare and define the function in the header, marking it `static`. This is not to be preffered, as it will create a copy of the function for each translation unit that includes the header.

To use the function, you need only include the header where it is declared and call it.

Answer (score 0):

header file (*.h)

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

source file (*.cpp)
at the top of the cpp file

```
#include "yourheader.h"
```

then anywhere in the cpp file

```
...
int result=add(5,6);
...
```